# formatting incorrect arguments in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function that takes in 3 arguments and sorts them in a proper sentence. for e.g.,

`echo formatExercise('There are {0} {1} in the tree!', 5, monkeys)`

The output should be: There are 5 monkeys in the tree!

I can do this by using sprtinf but I'm having problems implementing it as a full function that can take any arguments without changing the code (with sprintf is fine as well). For example:

```
<?php
function formatExercise() {
   $str = 'monkeys';
   $num = 5;

   $fmt = 'There are %d %s in the tree!';
   echo sprintf($fmt, $num, $str);
 }

echo formatExercise();
?>
```

The above gives us 'There are 5 monkeys in the tree!'

I am aware I have to pass arguments. My understanding is something like this:

```
function formatExercise($fmt, $num, $str)
```

But I'm not sure how to write the function. I'm a beginner so please can someone provide some insight.

Comment: Will the sentence always be "There are ... in the tree!"? Or might the sentence change?

Comment: it can change. its about formatting the arguments depending on what the position is... it will always be function (format string, 'string', number).

Comment: It is also unclear what the purpose of your three functions are: formatExercise(), formatByPosition(), fmtExercise(). Also, your first bit of code at the very top of your question apparently has string, number, string rather than string, string, number, so that is a bit confusing as well.

Comment: fixed some of the issues you mentioned. thanks

Comment: I have added a second example as well to my answer. Not sure which one you prefer though.

Comment: In your opening sentence you mention "sorts". Do you just mean "inserts"?

Answer (score -1):

This may be what you are after if you are wanting to use the {#} characters:

```
function splat ($sentence, $num, $creatures){
    $first_pass = str_replace('{0}', $num, $sentence);
    $second_pass = str_replace('{1}', $creatures, $first_pass);
    return $second_pass;
}

echo splat('There are {0} {1} in the tree', 5, "monkeys");
```

Or if you are preferring to use sprintf, you could do it this way:

```
function formatExercise($fmt, $num, $str) {
    echo sprintf($fmt, $num, $str);
}

echo formatExercise('There are %d %s in the tree!', 5, 'monkeys');
```

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I have read them, but maybe I am missing something that you are seeing. It would be more helpful if you could indicate where I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Here is a [link to the arguments section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for the `str_replace` function. You will notice that I have used the arguments correctly and have tested it as well. It is very likely that you are misunderstanding my code

Comment: you missing  the ability of passing an arrays

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I did not miss that ability. In fact, I use str_replace with arrays quite frequently. However, arrays are not necessary in this case. Based on his opening sentence he only ever needs to replace two needles and doesn't need a more generalized function. My answer is correct. If you disagree with my coding approach here, why not write your own answer?

Comment: I do not need to answer every question. Your code will work yet you call `str_replace()` for no benefit. That's the point.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, simply add to parameters:

```
function formatExercise($fmt, $var, $num)
{
    echo sprintf($fmt, $var, $num);
}

formatExercise('There are %2$d %1$s in the tree!', 'monkeys', 5);
```